# print(Select) the student_id, student_name from student table with marks of any two subjects greater than 90 out of 6 subjects

Tags: sql, oracle

you have a student table with student_id, student_name, subject1, subject2, subject3, subject4, subject5, subject6.
subject columns holds marks of student in respective subjects.

sample values

```
student_id|student_name|subject1|subject2|subject3|subject4|subject5|subject6
1 | 'a' | 48 | 98 | 69 | 89 | 75 | 91 
2 | 'b' | 58 | 84 | 59 | 79 | 74 | 92
3 | 'c' | 78 | 98 | 99 | 89 | 73 | 78
```

i had tried brute force approach, means selecting two conditions of s1>90 and s2>90 with OR conditions with permutations.

please avoid **brute force approach**. Also please send a code working in **sql plus**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and define what "brute force approach" means in this context. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any method is going to be rather brute force, because the data is structured so poorly.  You should have a table with one row per subject.

What you can do is add up the number that exceed 90 and use that in the `where` clause.  The following is standard SQL syntax and should work in any database:

```
where ( (case when subject1 > 90 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when subject2 > 90 then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .  -- replace with the rest of the subjects
        (case when subject6 > 90 then 1 else 0 end)
      ) >= 2
```

Comment: Maybe the OP needs a little hint as to what `structured so poorly` might mean? I would do this: `CREATE TABLE student (student_id INT, student_name VARCHAR(50), subject INT, subject_grade INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (student_id), UNIQUE (student_name));`. p.s. not great for Oracle syntax. To the OP, the question was `please avoid brute force approach. Also please send a code working in sql plus`. You'll get the best answer the data can give. My profile has a number of articles on how to ask db questions here - you might want to look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @Vérace - interesting list. Alas ESR's How to ask smart questions is the very definition of [unwelcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1). Also, this would make more sense as a comment on the question rather than Gordon's answer.

Comment: @APC . . . The comment was directed to my statement "structured so poorly".  Verace did not consider the following sentence to be sufficient explanation.